# Rename all variable sas

Tags: sas, rename

I have a database where 12,000 variables are named "A0122_40", "A0122_45", "A0122_50" and so on. I would like to rename them by keeping in the initial name the numbers from 2 to 5. I would then like to create variables adding all the columns with the same name.

Comment: Did you try to use `dictionary.columns`?

Comment: Do you want to append all columns that have prefix "a122"?

Comment: I don't understand.  Do you want to replace the three variables in your example with the SUM of their values?  `A0122=sum(of A0122_:); drop A0122_:;`

Comment: What have you tried ? Can you post some sample code for say only 5 variables (instead of 12,000) ?

Answer (score 0):

### CASE 1

If you want to join two tables with same column names, and keep all data:

```
data class;
set sashelp.class (obs=2);
rename name=A0122_40
    Sex=A0122_45
    Weight=A0122_50
    Height=A0122_55

;run;
```

Prepared Table:

```
+----------+----------+-----+----------+----------+
| A0122_40 | A0122_45 | Age | A0122_55 | A0122_50 |
+----------+----------+-----+----------+----------+
| Alfred   | M        |  14 |       69 |    112.5 |
| Alice    | F        |  13 |     56.5 |       84 |
+----------+----------+-----+----------+----------+
```

Code to rename:

```
%macro renameCols(lb , ds);
proc sql noprint;
    select name
        into :rn_vr1-
            from dictionary.columns
                where LIBNAME=upcase("&lb") AND MEMNAME=upcase("&ds")
                    AND NAME LIKE 'A0122%'
    ;
    %let num_vars = &sqlobs.;

proc datasets library=&lb nolist nodetails nowarn;
    modify &ds;
    rename

        %do i=1 %to &num_vars;
            &&rn_vr&i=new_&&rn_vr&i
        %end;
    ;
%mend renameCols;
%renameCols(work,class);
```

Result Table:

```
+--------------+--------------+-----+--------------+--------------+
| new_A0122_40 | new_A0122_45 | Age | new_A0122_55 | new_A0122_50 |
+--------------+--------------+-----+--------------+--------------+
| Alfred       | M            |  14 |           69 |        112.5 |
| Alice        | F            |  13 |         56.5 |           84 |
+--------------+--------------+-----+--------------+--------------+
```

As you see, all columns were renamed, exclude Age.

---

### CASE 2

If you want to "append" all A0122_... in one , I suggest the next code:

```
data class;
    set sashelp.class (obs=2);
    rename name=A0123_40
        Sex=A0123_45
        Weight=A0122_50
        Height=A0121_55

    ;
run;
```

Prepared Table:

```
+----------+----------+-----+----------+----------+
| A0123_40 | A0123_45 | Age | A0121_55 | A0122_50 |
+----------+----------+-----+----------+----------+
| Alfred   | M        |  14 |       69 |    112.5 |
| Alice    | F        |  13 |     56.5 |       84 |
+----------+----------+-----+----------+----------+
```

Code to rename:

```
%macro renameCols(lb , ds);

%macro d;
%mend d;

    proc sql noprint;
    select name
        into :rn_vr1-
            from dictionary.columns
                where LIBNAME=upcase("&lb") AND MEMNAME=upcase("&ds")
                    AND NAME LIKE 'A012%'
    ;
    %let num_vars = &sqlobs.;

    /*Create a lot of tables with one column from one input*/
    data 
    %do i=1 %to &num_vars;
        &&rn_vr&i (rename=(&&rn_vr&i=%scan(&&rn_vr&i,1,_)) keep = &&rn_vr&i )
    %end;
    ;
    set &lb..&ds.;
    run;

    /*Count variable patterns and write it to macro*/
    proc sql noprint;
        select distinct scan(name,1,'_')
            into :aggr_vars1-
                from dictionary.columns
                    where LIBNAME=upcase("&lb") AND MEMNAME=upcase("&ds")
                        AND NAME LIKE 'A012%'
    ;
    %let num_aggr_vars=&sqlobs.;

    /*Append all tables that contains same column name pattern*/
    %do i=1 %to &num_aggr_vars;
        data _&&aggr_vars&i;
            set &&aggr_vars&i:;
            n=_n_;
        run;
    %end;

    /*Merge that tables into one*/
    data res (drop= n);
        merge 
            %do i=1 %to &num_aggr_vars;
        _&&aggr_vars&i
        %end;
        ;
        by n;
    run;

    run;

%mend renameCols;

%renameCols(work,class);
```

The res table:

```
+-------+-------+--------+
| A0121 | A0122 | A0123  |
+-------+-------+--------+
|    69 | 112.5 | Alfred |
|  56.5 |    84 | Alice  |
|     . |     . | M      |
|     . |     . | F      |
+-------+-------+--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
proc contents data=have out=cols noprint;
run;

proc sql noprint;
  select distinct substr(name,1,6) into :colgrps separated by " " from cols;
run;

%macro process;

data want;
  set have;
  %let ii = 1;

  %do %while (%scan(&colgrps, &ii, %str( )) ~= );
    %let grp = %scan(&colgrps, &ii, %str( ));
    &grp._sum = sum(of &grp.:);
    %let ii = %eval(&ii + 1);
  %end;

run;
%mend;

%process;
```